# ngx-smart-modal - Angular 6

Tags: modal-dialog, angular6

I followed this [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-smart-modal-example) to add te `ngx-smart-modal` window.

Everything went well, except the component opens on the page instead of in a Lightbox modal pop-up.

This example is using Angular 4.

Has anybody used this module in Angular 6 successfully?

Comment: Did you add the Css file to the project?

Comment: We can't help you without the code ^^'

Comment: Adding the css file refrence in angular.json file did the trick.

Comment: I've followed the same StackBlitz example and facing the same problem, even after importing the css file in my angular json, after doing some debugging, the NgxSmartModalService modalStack is empty and never register these wrapped components

Answer (score 3):

For ngx-smart-modal v7.1.0, I simply added the .css or .scss (.scss in my case since that is the default file extension I have setup in my Angular project) file to the styles section of your angular.json.

```
"styles": [
  ...
  "node_modules/ngx-smart-modal/ngx-smart-modal.scss",
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Add ngxSmartModal's style in your global style.css (or .scss) as :

```
@import "~ngx-smart-modal/ngx-smart-modal";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the lower version of 'ngx-smart-modal'.
e.g npm install ngx-smart-modal@2.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Change the ngx-smart-modal dependency version in package.json file like this.

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"ngx-smart-modal": "2.0.4",
"rxjs": "~6.2.0",
"web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
"zone.js": "~0.8.26"  }
```

Then reinstall the npm modules by using command "npm install"