# How to add the css file reference in angular.json? ngx-smart-modal - Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I followed this StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-smart-modal-example to add the ngx-smart-modal window, but the component opens on the page instead of in a modal pop-up.  Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem, or how to add the css file reference if that's what solves the problem?

- I tied many things,
- I tried following the first 2 answers of this post: [ngx-smart-modal - Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086099/ngx-smart-modal-angular-6)
  but with no luck:
- I tried adding the line:

"node_modules/ngx-smart-modal/ngx-smart-modal.css",

to the section:

```
 "styles": [
          ],
```

in the angular.json

- I tried adding the line:

  @import "../node_modules/ngx-smart-modal/ngx-smart-modal.css";

into the src/styles.css file as well as adding: the line: 
     "src/styles.css"
to the section

```
"styles": [    
              ],
```

in the angular.json

```
...

       "styles": [

              "./node_modules/ngx-smart-modal/ngx-smart-modal.css"

        ],
...
```

Comment: Follow their official tutorial: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-smart-modal

Answer (score 0):

Your stackblitz example use ngx-smart-modal@2.0.4, however we are currently in @7.1.1.

I recommand you to follow the official documentation for [Setup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-smart-modal#setup) your modals.

Instead of absolute path, use relativ path as `@import "~ngx-smart-modal/ngx-smart-modal.css";`

Answer (score 0):

I followed some steps but with no luck, so I moved to another example that did work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jm9q9Alva0M with code at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-modal

but I had to add the line:
< link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

at the top of the "app.component.html" file, then the modal page showed up.

Comment: That's unfortunately not the same package. It's not an answer of your issue.